# How to post items for sale via an API on Instagram

Tags: instagram, e-commerce, instagram-api

Instagram provides a way for people to sell stuff via posts and stories on their platform [0](https://help.instagram.com/191462054687226)

I notice that, for example, Shopify offers [1](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-online/instagram) a way to post products for sale from their platform to Instagram for sale.

However, Instagram does not appear to document an API for this [2](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

What mechanisms/APIs/hacks can one use to publish items in an automated way for sale on Instagram?

Comment: did you ever find anything?

Comment: Nope . I have not looked into it in the past two years though so maybe things have changed.  Good luck